# How do I make local variable used in global?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, global, local

So I am trying to write rows in csv in python, and my code look like this. But it won't write because those variables are local? How do I do it? Thank you! There is no error shows, it's write no row in csv.
And when I run it in pycharm on mac, it works, but after I make it an exe on windows, it doesn't write row.

```
types=[]
row=[]
col=[]
image_number=[]
def click(event):
    global rectangle
    global image_list1
    types.append(v.get())
    row.append(event.x)
    col.append(event.y)
    filename = image_list1[0]
    image_number.append(filename)
    x1, y1 = (event.x -3), (event.y- 3)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 3), (event.y + 3)
    rectangle=w.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2,fill=color[v.get()-1],outline="")
if image_length:
    root.tk()
    w.bind("<Button-1>", click)
    root=mainloop()
    d.writerows(zip(image_number, types, row, col))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `return` statement is for:

```
types=[]
row=[]
col=[]
image_number=[]
def click(event):
    global rectangle
    global image_enum
    global image_list1
    types.append(v.get())
    row.append(event.x)
    col.append(event.y)
    filename = image_list1[0]
    image_number.append(filename)
    return (image_number, types, row, col)
if image_length:
    image_number, types, row, col = click(event)
    d.writerows(zip(image_number, types, row, col))
```

Or if you want to be fancy:

```
if image_length:
    d.writerows(zip(*click(event)))
```

Of course, you need an event defined first!

Comment: You can also just write `d.writerows(zip(*click(event)))`

Comment: And you beat me by two seconds... :P

Comment: I'm wondering though if `image_number` should really be `filename` that is returned. Otherwise, you'd just be passing a growing list to `zip` everytime...

Comment: There are probably a few issues here (like the global variables that don't get used, for starters).

Comment: It still doesn't work, weird thing is it works on ios, but not on windows. Anyone know why?

Comment: What kind of "doesn't work"? Please post the error message or incorrect output (you can edit this into your question.)

Comment: On second thought, this looks like a separate issue; it's probably better to roll back those edits and start a new question. Sorry for the miscommunication. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted